# Decoding JSON file from Twitter in Python using simplejson

Tags: python, json, twitter

A small part of my JSON file looks like the following. It passed  a JSON validator. (I added cl

```
{
"next_page": "?page=2&max_id=210389654296469504&q=cocaine&geocode=40.665572%2C-73.923557%2C10mi&rpp=100",
"completed_in": 0.289,
"max_id_str": "210389654296469504",
"since_id_str": "0",
"refresh_url": "?since_id=210389654296469504&q=cocaine&geocode=40.665572%2C-73.923557%2C10mi",
"results": [
    {
        "iso_language_code": "en",
        "to_user_id": 486935435,
        "to_user_id_str": "486935435",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1561856049/Zak_W_Photo_normal.jpg",
        "from_user_id_str": "82389940",
        "text": "@Bill__Murray cocaine &gt; productivity! Last night I solved the euro crisis and designed a new cat. If I could only find that napkin.",
        "from_user_name": "Zak Williams",
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": "210319741322133504",
        "profile_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1561856049/Zak_W_Photo_normal.jpg",
        "id": 210389654296469500,
        "to_user": "Bill__Murray",
        "source": "&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitter.com/#!/download/iphone&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;Twitter for iPhone&lt;/a&gt;",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": 210319741322133500,
        "to_user_name": "Bill Murray",
        "location": "Brooklyn",
        "from_user": "zakwilliams",
        "from_user_id": 82389940,
        "metadata": {
            "result_type": "recent"
        },
        "geo": "null",
        "created_at": "Wed, 06 Jun 2012 15:16:17 +0000",
        "id_str": "210389654296469504"
    }
]
}
```

When I try to load this in Python by typing the following code I get the following error.

**Code**

```
 import simplejson as json
 testname = 'test.txt'
 record = json.loads(testname)
```

**Error**

```
 raise JSONDecodeError("No JSON object could be decoded", s, idx)
 simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError: No JSON object could be decoded: line 1 column 0 (char 0)
```

What am I doing wrong? In fact, I generated the file by using `simplejson.dump`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `json.loads()` function loads JSON data from a *string*, and you are just giving it a file name. The string `test.txt` is not a valid JSON string. Try the following to load JSON data from a file:

```
with open(testname) as f:
    record = json.load(f)
```

(If you're using an old version of Python that doesn't support the `with` statement (as possibly indicated by your use of the old `simplejson`), then you'll have to open and close the file yourself.)

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7. What's the newer version of simplejson?

Comment: It's just called `json` and is part of the standard Python library (it has the same interface).